# Moq cannot create mock object of class with nullable parameter in the constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, nullable

I have this class:

```
public class TestClass
{
 public TestClass(int? foo, string bar)
 {
   //..Something
 }
}
```

I am trying to mock it using MOQ like this

```
var mockA = new Mock<A>(new object[] {(int?)1, string.Empty})
```

or this,

```
var mockA = new Mock<A>(new object[] {1 as int?, string.Empty})
```

even this

```
var mockA = new Mock<A>(new object[] {(int?)null, string.Empty})
```

When I try to get the object like this

```
var objA = mockA.Object
```

it throws this exception

Can not instantiate proxy of class: TestClass.
Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
System.Int32,
System.String

(for the third one it throws null reference exception)

How to make it recognize that first argument is of type Nullable System.Int32 and not System.Int32.

(Please ignore that I am mocking a class and not an interface.)

Comment: Note: this issue does not exist in Moq 4.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>In order to Mock an object with Moq, the object itself must have a `public` empty constructor.</strike>
Methods you want to mock must be `virtual` in order to be overridden.

**Edit:**

I'm running Moq v4.0.20926 (latest from NuGet) and the following work:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var mock = new Mock<TestClass>(new object[] {null, null});
    mock.Setup(m => m.MockThis()).Returns("foo");

    Assert.AreEqual("foo", mock.Object.MockThis());
}

public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(int? foo, string bar)
    {
    }

    public virtual string MockThis()
    {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you dont have a default constructor, You can pass an object array to the params argument in Moq. Right? Thats what I am trying to do here.

Comment: That should work, yes. I've updated my answer with some code that work on my computer.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that boxing a nullable value doesn't really box the `Nullable<T>` value, it boxes the value inside.

Basically:

1. If you box a nullable value that *has* a value, you get a boxed version of the value, so a boxed version of `(int?)1` is the same as a boxed version of `1`
2. If you box a nullable value that *does not* have a value, you get a null-reference, which has no type

You can think of the boxing operation as similar to this:

```
public static object Box(int? value)
{
    if (value.HasValue)
        return value.Value; // boxes the int value

    return null;            // has no type
}
```

In other words, your `object[]` array doesn't get a copy of the nullable value at all, it just gets a copy of the `int` value, or a `null`-reference, neither of which carries the `Nullable<T>` type.

Here's some [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) code to test:

```
void Main()
{
    int? i = 1;
    object o = i;

    o.Dump();
    o.GetType().Dump();

    i = null;
    o = i;
    o.Dump();
    o.GetType().Dump();
}
```

Output:

> 1
>   System.Int32
>   *null*
>   [NullReferenceException]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I was starting to think that this was the case. Any ideas??

Comment: To be honest, this looks like either a bug or an oversight in the creation of the Moq library, they should add support for the coercion necessary to handle this. But that's just my opinion.