# Moq - Unexpected behaviour when SetUp for a method with nullable parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

When passing null value for nullable param, Moq ignores the SetUp and behaves as per its default MockBehavior (Loose).

```
public interface INumberGen
{
    //Also fails if marked as an optional param (int? greaterThan = null)
    int GenerateNumber(int? greaterThan);
}

public class NumberProvider
{
    private readonly INumberGen numberGen;

    public NumberProvider(INumberGen numberGen)
    {
        this.numberGen = numberGen;
    }

    public int GetANumber(int? greaterThan)
    {
        return numberGen.GenerateNumber(greaterThan);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class NumberProviderTests
{
    private Mock<INumberGen> mockNumberGen;
    private NumberProvider sut;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        mockNumberGen = new Mock<INumberGen>();
        sut = new NumberProvider(mockNumberGen.Object);
    }

    [TestCase(-1, 100)]
    [TestCase(0, 233)]
    [TestCase(-777, -99)]
    [TestCase(null, 255)] //Fails, not going through explicit setup (return is based on default behaviour [loose mock])
    public void GetANumber_Returns_SameValueReturnedByNumberGen_Test(
        int? greaterThan,
        int expected)
    {
        mockNumberGen
            .Setup(x => x.GenerateNumber(It.IsAny<int?>()))
            .Returns(expected);

        var actual = sut.GetANumber(greaterThan: greaterThan);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

[TestCase(null, 255)] that calls the mocked method with null argument doesn't return the expected value. Is this the expected Moq behaviour for nullable types?

Comment: Just a notice. If you mock the generator itself, it is pointless to run all that test. You just have to check if method is called and the tested method return the result of the mocked method.

Comment: Which version do you use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378223/moq-cannot-create-mock-object-of-class-with-nullable-parameter-in-the-constructo Lasse's answer explains a lot!

Comment: @Peter, It's Moq : 4.2.1506.2016. Your first point agree top 3 TestCases are redundant, but the above code and the fixture are only for demo purpose, not real code.

Comment: Worked like a charm with NSubstitute, another reason to switch to NSubs